# Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 vs Advanced-N 6200 2x2

Tags: wireless-networking

Does the Ultimate-N 6300 actually offer better performance than the 6200?

Are there any stats or benchmarks to show the difference?

Also, what about battery performance? Does using the extra stream consume significantly more battery?